# Q. How can i select one image on image layers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, layer

(Please understand, English may be a mess.)

Try the first question in here.

I'm a student studying web programming. I make a Web Game. Use HTML, JavaScript. Not use Adobe Flash.

When, how can I select one image on image layers? I made two images. Use a web-photoshop.

1. `BackGround.png`

   This image has no function. just background image.
2. `go_Lobby.png`

   This image has two function.

   - Function `onClick = " go_Lobby() "`

     `href = "Lobby.html"`, go to the lobby page.
   - Function `onMouseOver = " OverEvent() "`

     Using effect at image when your mouse on image.

Below is the code:

```
<script>
  function go_lobby{<br/>
    location.herf="lobby.html";<br/>
  }
</script>
<body>
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index = 99;">
    <img src = "map.png"/>
  </div>
  <div style="posistion:absolute; z-index = 10;">
    <img src = "go_lobby.png" onclick = " go_lobby() " onMouseOver ="" />
  </div>
</body>
```

But unlike my idea was to move the page when you click anywhere in the lobby.

How can you move to the page only when selecting the "Lobby" image?

Comment: what do you mean by 'move the page' / 'move to the page'?

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting the lobby image" ?

Comment: Why do you have `<br />` in your javascript snippet? Is this just a formatting issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is flawed.

- `href` is spelt incorrectly - so you won't be redirected.
- You have `<br/>` in your JavaScript, which will cause the second line to not execute.
- You're missing the parenthesis on the function declaration.

Change your JavaScript to become the following

```
<script>
  function go_lobby() {
    window.location.href = "lobby.html";
  }
</script>
```

Now, when you `onclick` the `go_lobby.png` image, a call will be made to `go_lobby()` function, which will redirect the window to `lobby.html`.

#### Test runs

With your current JavaScript, you would have gotten these errors (looking at [**the console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers))

- `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
- `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
- No page redirect

Answer (score 1):

This is an absolute mess..

JavaScript code should not have HTML tags in it unless it's inside of a string. Also you have a typo - it's `location.href` not `location.herf`. Furthermore if you're defining a function in JavaScript it should have a function keyword, function name, function arguments and then the function body. If you want to redirect with JavaScript you can simply use `window.location`.

Fix your JavaScript part to the following:

```
<script>
    function go_lobby() {
        window.location = "lobby.html";
    }
</script>
```

You also have a typo in your HTML. `posistion` should be `position`. Empty element attributes are redundant if they aren't set beforehand. Also if your setting an event event for an event like `onclick` then the spaces that you have there are just useless and can lead to problems.

Fix your HTML to:

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index = 99;">
        <img src="map.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index = 10;">
        <img src="go_lobby.png" onclick="go_lobby()" />
    </div>
</body>
```

After this the image onclick event should trigger the redirect.

Comment: Good spot on the `posistion`! I failed to spot that in my answer. +1